# Strange Bug in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, uibutton, title

I found a strange bug in iphone sdk. I try to explain it:

I have a number of uibuttons in a view. They are all just images. Every buttons has a title but that is not displayed so you just see the images (all 80x80). I made it all in IB.
In my code I position those buttons. Here's a snippet of that code:

```
    for(NSString *iconObject in iconArray){
  //retrieve UIButtons from dictionary
  iconButton = [allIconsDictionary objectForKey:iconObject];
  iconButton.hidden = NO;
  //position and resize icon Buttons
  iconButton.frame = CGRectMake((79 * col) + 28, (70 * row) + 70, 80 ,80);

  col++;

  //five buttons in a row
  if(col%5 == 0){
   row++;
   col = 0;
  }
 }
```

That works like it should. But for all buttons that title starts with a 't' the title displays in the simulator (also on the device). The title of the other buttons are not shown just those where the title starts with a 't'.
I have no clue what this could be?!

I hope I could describe the problem.

Comment: I don't see any code here that manipulates button titles or their visibility.  Why don't you trace (perhaps using NSLog) the code as it does this, and hopefully you will see what you've done wrong (and I'm guessing that your code is failing to correctly set the visibility of the button titles, rather than the SDK being bugged).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried iconButton.titleLabel.hidden = YES; But that changed nothing. The 't' titles are still displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused - you say they all have an image *and* a title that's not displayed - why bother with a title at all then?

I'm guessing that your your images aren't all the same size.

Some buttons are big enough to get the image and the first letter of the title in them. The other buttons have images the correct size so the title isn't displayed.

Comment: Thanks man. It has been the image size. I know that it seems a bit strange with the titles but I need them :-)